# Org mode table export latex with title (upper) and notes (lower)

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I would like to create the following LaTeX type table by ***using the standard org-mode functions***.

[image]

The LaTeX code is the following:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Results}
\label{tab}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\hline
\hline 
& (1) & (2) & (3) \\
\hline
XXX & 1.60 & 2.38 & 2.80 \\
 & (1.60) & (0.98) & (1.26) \\
Observations & 20 & 20 & 20 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item 
\hspace{-12pt}\emph{Notes:}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

In the org table editor, I can create a similar result.

```
#+NAME: tab1
#+CAPTION: Results
|--------------+--------+--------+--------|
|--------------+--------+--------+--------|
|              | (1)    | (2)    | (3)    |
|--------------+--------+--------+--------|
| XXX          | 1.60   | 2.38   | 2.80   |
|              | (1.60) | (0.98) | (1.26) |
| Observations |  20    | 20     |  20    |
|--------------+--------+--------+--------|
```

But, I would like to understand how to add the ***Note*** by using org mode.

Comment: Not sure to fully understand what you want, but it might be enough to set the variable `org-latex-caption-above` to the desired value. If this does not work, maybe you should provide the orgmode code you tried, the output you got and what you'd like to get.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I just edited the original question. I think the meaning become more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I found something which is a good workaround, but probably not a good solution.

1. First you'll have to set (as local variables) the variables `org-latex-caption-above` to `t` (so as to the get the caption above the table and not below), and `org-latex-tables-centered` to `nil`. This second setting aims to avoid your `threeparttable` environment to be enclosed in `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`, which triggers an error.
2. This minimal example does seem to work, but it is rather rather ugly and not very convenient:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{threeparttable}
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil

#+NAME: tab1
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment tabu :align lrrr
#+begin_table
#+CAPTION: Results
#+begin_threeparttable
|--------------+--------+--------+--------|
|--------------+--------+--------+--------|
|              | (1)    | (2)    | (3)    |
|--------------+--------+--------+--------|
| XXX          | 1.60   | 2.38   | 2.80   |
|              | (1.60) | (0.98) | (1.26) |
| Observations |  20    | 20     |  20    |
|--------------+--------+--------+--------|
#+begin_tablenotes
\item Source: my source.
#+end_tablenotes
#+end_threeparttable
#+end_table

* Lisp setup                                                       :noexport:
;;; Local variables:
;;; org-latex-caption-above: t
;;; org-latex-tables-centered: nil
;;; End:
```

I do not have better to propose... but you can use this as a skeleton (with `yasnippet` or something similar) to avoid all this typing each time.

Comment: Thanks. To set "center" option for the whole table, I have to use "center" option like the following, right?

```
#+begin_table
#+begin_center
~~
#+end_center
#+end_table

Comment: Yes, I guess! Or a `\centring` instruction somewhere. Or anything (manually added) that does play well with the `threeparttable` environement.